# rendering a list including pictures

Tags: reactjs

I’m rendering a list of objects and all is working fine.

But now I would like to add pictures to the array of objects but I can’t seem to get the image to render.

I have imported said image.

And my array looks like this :

```
       Import image from ‘./rusty.jpg’ ;

Class dogList extends Component{
  Constructor (props){
     Super(props);

  this.state={
    dogs: [
      {Name: ‘rusty’, sex:’male’, age:10, image:{image}},
      {Name: ‘rusty’, sex:’male’, age:10, image:{image}},
      {Name: ‘rusty’, sex:’male’, age:10, image:{image}},
       ]
     }
  }
```

Etc...

I know my import is fine because I have tried to render it elsewhere and it works. I’m pretty certain my error is in the state. I have also tried placing it in there as components

```
<img src={image}/>
```

however none are working

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Please post the code showing how you are rendering the image inside the render function.

Comment: I didn’t show my render because I have filters and search box components and I knew it was going to be something simple. Sorted!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the curly braces:

```
{Name: ‘rusty’, sex:’male’, age:10, image: image},
```

In ES6 you can even remove the semicolon:

```
{Name: ‘rusty’, sex:’male’, age:10, image},
```

When you render it, pass it as `src` prop to the `img` tag:

```
<img src={ dog.image } />
```

Comment: That fixed it thanks for your I knew it was going to be something really basic. Thanks

Comment: My next issue is going to be. If I have hundreds if not thousands I’m my array. How can I have an image for each without having to have a thousand imports. Is it possible to call the image from a directory without importing it first ?